# in otrs: How to show a dynamic field checkbox in a template as a checked checkbox

Tags: templates, checkbox, otrs

I've a dynamic field checkbox that can be selected during a process in otrs. At the end of the process a mail have to be sent with a template inside that summarize the information collected in the process stored in multiple dynamic fields, the only one that I can't figure out how to show as a checked/unchecked checkbox is... the checkbox. If I poit on

I'm workin in this enviroment: Erizone 5.3.0 on OTRS 5.0.25

If I point on

```
<OTRS_TICKET_DynamicField_CheckBox1>
```

I receive as result

```
1
```

If I point on

```
<OTRS_TICKET_DynamicField_CheckBox1_Value>
```

I receive as result

```
Checked
```

I want to show at least a mark when the checkbox is checked

Answer (score 0):

You have to add some HTML to it.

```
 <input type="checkbox" readonly name="CheckBox1" <OTRS_TICKET_DynamicField_CheckBox1_Value>>
```

The value of the tag will make it display as checked or unchecked.

Comment: Hi, I've tried to implement your solution, but the editor keep normalizing my html erasing the line.

Comment: Try to use the source code mode of CKEditor. Just be careful that you don't escape the actual OTRS dynamic field tag.

Comment: Try to open the source code mode and enter this to the correct space `<input type="checkbox" readonly name="CheckBox1" &lt;OTRS_TICKET_DynamicField_CheckBox1_Value&gt;>` and save without switching back to the normal mode. A refresh could delete the code, but the correct one should be saved in the database.

Comment: hi, using the source code is what I do normally when I've to modify a template. Anyway I tried as you proposed to save without coming back to the normal mode but it didn't worked either.

Comment: Btw I've ended using a second dynamic Field for displaying purpose only and two agent that change the displaying DF accordingly with the check box when is changed.